# Encrypted separate home partition with Ubuntu, now moving to CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, centos, disk-encryption

Do I need to to decrypt the home partition before I move, or does CentOS support the encryption methods that Ubuntu uses? Hopping between Ubuntu distros is no problem at all, but I think I might have problems with this.

Comment: I don't think there are proprietary Ubuntu encryption schemes. What is the current encryption scheme? LUKS?

Comment: yes, but after installing, will CentOS know this drive is encrypted and needs to be decrypted before use

Comment: during the install process, it seems oblivious to that fact

Comment: If it's a separate partition you can alter how it is mounted. See https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/how-to-mount-a-luks-encrypted-partition-on-boot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lost my data. To future readers, save your data to an external drive :)